# Storybook AddDecorators doesn't provide the redux store

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, storybook

I am using Storybook and React-Redux.

I have a global decorator in `preview.js`, which adds the store like so:

```js
import { addDecorator } from '@storybook/react';
import ProviderWrapper from '../src/components/Provider'; //Provides the store

addDecorator(storyFn => <ProviderWrapper>{storyFn()}</ProviderWrapper>
```

The ProviderWrapper is just (more or less):

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from '../redux/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();
export const ProviderWrapper = ({ children }) =>
    (<Provider store={store}>{children}</Provider>)
```

Configure store is currently very simple: `const configureStore = () => createStore(reducers);`

The issue I have is that when I try to use react-redux hooks in one of my components, and set it up I get this error message:

```
could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>
```

My Component uses the store like so:

```js
const MyLovelyComponent = () => {
   const { myData, lovelyData } = useSelector(selectMyLovelyData);
   return (
      <Paper>
        <MyComponent data={myData} />
        <LovelyComponent data={lovelyData} />
      </Paper>
   );
};
```

And when I use it in a story I have it set up in this way:

```js
export default {
    title: 'MyLovelyComponent',
    Component: MyLovelyComponent
}

export const UsingRedux = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(updateMyData(myData)); // actionCreator for updating state
      dispatch(updateLovelyData(lovelyData));
    }, []);
    return (<MyLovelyComponent />);
}
```

It feels like everything should be set up to work, so I can't figure out why I am getting that error.

---

If it helps,here os my dependency treefpr react/redux etc. This may be relevant based on this [github issue](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1489):

```
transformation-comparison@1.0.0 /home/centos/transformation-comparison
┠─┰ @storybook/addon-actions@5.3.18
│ ┠─┰ @storybook/api@5.3.18
│ │ └── react@16.13.1  deduped
│ ┠─┰ @storybook/components@5.3.18
│ │ └── react@16.13.1  deduped
│ └── react@16.13.1  deduped
┠─┰ @storybook/react@5.3.18
│ └─┰ @storybook/core@5.3.18
│   └─┰ @storybook/ui@5.3.18
│     └── react@16.13.1  deduped
┠── react@16.13.1 
┠── react-redux@7.2.0 
└── redux@4.0.5
```

Again, no sure if it is relevant but on the off chance it helps I've included it.

Comment: From the code you posted, it does not look like the redux store is instantiated? That is, where is the `store` that is passed as a prop in `ProviderWrapper`?

Comment: @nrako I've added details!

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @DanieleRicci I tried to approximate that with my snippets, but I can never find a good way to make succinct MCVE for things like React/Angular etc. Do you have any suggestions for facilitating that?

Comment: @Pureferret Many people creates a public repos we could clone and run

Comment: @danielricci unfortunately I can't share my code, but given time I could make something in a codepen maybe?

Comment: @DanieleRicci I've started a codepen here, but I can't get it to work: https://codepen.io/ancientswordrage/pen/GRoQeeo?editors=0011

Comment: @nrako did my earlier update help at all?

Comment: Stopping by to review again. It's not clear to me why the context is getting dropped from a React standpoint. I might suggest simplifying the wrapper, dropping the `children` and use the `storyFn` directly.

`const store = configureStore()

const ProviderWrapper = (storyFn) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    { storyFn() }
  </Provider>
)
`
and then in the config
`addDecorator(ProviderWrapper);`
My guess is that it is related to the conflict you mentioned in the GH issue, but I'm not sure how to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've resolved my issue by moving the code from the decorator into the story itself. Long term this is not ideal, obviously.

```
export default {
    title: 'MyLovelyComponent',
    Component: MyLovelyComponent
}

const UsingReduxComponent = () => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
      dispatch(updateMyData(myData)); // actionCreator for updating state
      dispatch(updateLovelyData(lovelyData));
    }, []);
    return (<MyLovelyComponent />);
}

export const UsingRedux = () => (
    <ProviderWrapper>
        <UsingReduxComponent />
    </ProviderWrapper>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass store in both provider and wrapper also.

```js
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { configureStore } from '../redux/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

const ProviderWrapper = ({ children, store }) => (
    <Provider store={store}>
        {children}
    </Provider>
);

export const withProvider = (story) => (
    <ProviderWrapper store={store}>
        {story()}
    </ProviderWrapper>
)


// in config.js file

import { withProvider } from './Provider.js';
addDecorator(withProvider);
```

Comment: Checkout my first code block, I've just combined the `withProvider` into it. I pass the store in one place, not both to avoid ambiguity. Also your code block doesn't run without erroring, so I can't tell if your set up would actually work.